# Data label is missing in clustered column chart for Nov 2022 in power bi

Tags: powerbi, visualization

Issue : Data label is missing in clustered column chart for Nov 2022
Requirement :  Last 3 months data (base date +previous 2 months ) should be shown with all labels in x-axis and y-axis
Note : I have selected x-axis types both continuous and Categorical as well in format visual section

See below I have selected Base date as “ 1/10/2023” ( jan-10-2023)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCuTz.png)

Result fetch base date month +previous 2 months, but Label is missing for Nov 22 month

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubPyj.png)
For 4 month result ,Label is missing for oct 22
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRLH8.png)

--- I have tried x-axis type for both “continuous  and categorical , if we select categorical .. it is showing all months with labels
But my requirement is only display data based on based date selection.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEXId.png)

Hi ,

Data labels should be display correctly for all months , kindly help me .

Thanks & Regards
saivenkat

Comment: It is going to be guess work to help you. Please create & share a minimal viable PBIX that demonstrates the problem. What X-Axis are you using for the chart?